# Where is the bluez-hcidump package?

Tags: 14.10

On my Utopic installation `aptitude search hcidump` outputs nothing, despite what [Launchpad says](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/utopic/+package/bluez-hcidump) about the `bluez-hcidump` package.

There's a [`deb` file](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/bluez-hcidump/2.5-1/+build/4818494/+files/bluez-hcidump_2.5-1_amd64.deb) downloadable from Launchpad, but it doesn't seem to be in the repo.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

The Launchpad page [for one of the binary versions](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/utopic/amd64/bluez-hcidump/2.5-1) says that its status is *Deleted*, and the LP page for [the source package](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/bluez-hcidump/2.5-1) only shows a publishing history up to 14.04. The package is no longer available for 14.10.

Answer (score 1):

The package re-appeared in 15.10 and is now part of the [bluez 5 source package](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/bluez/5.35-0ubuntu2) as far as I can tell.